# Elements of a widget blueprint do not appear if I click on simulate

Tags: unreal-4, hud

I made a widget that contains 2 minimaps and 2 texts related to a character's variables.

**When I click the play button (Selected Viewport) everything happens fine:**

[image]

Focus where I circled in pink.

**It turns out that when I click the Simulate button, these two texts do not appear, but the minimaps do:**

[image]

I did a test by first clicking the play button (Selected Viewport) and then I ejected the character (which for me is the same thing as simulating, except without closing and opening the game) and the texts appeared, so my problem is only when I'm done start simulating.

I would like to know how to make these 2 texts appear even if I click on simulate instead of play.